# Problem related to topology coinduced by continuous maps

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that a set $X$ has some topology $\mathcal{T}$. Show that the continuous maps $f: X \to X$ coinduces the same topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$.

I'm not sure, but I feel like this is false. The coinduced topology $\mathcal{T}'$ is the finest topology such that the maps $f$ are continuous. This means that either $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}'$ or $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$. But I don't know anything about $\mathcal{T}$ except that it's a topology on $X$. When does the equality occur since that's what I think I need?

Comment: Coinduce = final topology presumably?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology) seems to agree.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. For example, if $f$ is a constant, then the topology coinduced will be the discrete one. But $\mathcal{T}$ need not be discrete to begin with.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I think OP is talking about the finest topology w.r.t which **every** continuous map $f: X \to X$ is continuous. $f$ is not fixed in this statement.

Comment: Indeed $f$ is not fixed here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Ah thanks, that makes more sense. I'll leave the comment since it may be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s be precise:

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{f: X \to X\mid f \text{ continuous wrt } \mathcal{T} \text{ on both domain and codomain } \}$

Let $\mathcal{T}’$ be the coinduced topology on $X$ by $\mathcal{F}$, where the *domain* of $f$ has topology $\mathcal{T}$ (this must be specified).

Then, as $\mathcal{T}$ is *one* topology that makes all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ continuous we get by maximality that $$\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T’}\tag{1}$$

But as $1_X$ (the identity function) is in $\mathcal{F}$ too, obviously, we get that $1_X:(X,\mathcal{T}) \to (X,\mathcal{T’})$ is continuous by definition so that

$$\mathcal{T’} \subseteq \mathcal T\tag{2}$$

$(1) $and $(2)$ together give equality of topologies.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the question is not vague. My interpretation is correct.